# Reddit button callback function

Tags: javascript, wordpress, callback

I'm using infinite scroll on one of my Wordpress installs, and was experiencing an issue when loading new posts as the social buttons didn't load.

I fixed this by adding the following into the callback for Facebook like button and Twitter share. However I haven't been able to find a similar solution for the Reddit submit button.

```
 twttr.widgets.load();
 FB.XFBML.parse();
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!

My markup including the button:

```
 <div class="socialshare">
 <div class="reddit">
 <script type="text/javascript">
 reddit_url = "<?php the_permalink(); ?>";
 reddit_newwindow = "1";
 </script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://en.reddit.com/static/button/button1.js"></script>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe Reddit doesn't have a fancy JavaScript API.
An easy solution would be to just grab the code from [this script](http://www.reddit.com/buttonlite.js?i=0&url=foo.com&newwindow=1) (example link).
In your callback function run through all corresponding HTML elements where you want to display the buttons and then execute the code there.

Comment: Sounds like this would be beyond my javascript knowledge. I tried using the example you linked to, but seemed to redirect me when loading the new posts. Would you be able to give me a working example? I've added the button code above.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you use the jQuery library on your website?

Comment: Yeah I use jQuery throughout the site